# How do I sort using the best matching nested field or a default in Elasticsearch?

Tags: sorting, elasticsearch

I have a bunch of documents that look like this in my index:

```json
{
    "given_name":"John",
    "family_name":"Smith",
    "email_addresses": [
        {
          "email_address":"john@gmail.com",
          "primary":true
        },
        {
          "email_address":"j.smith@gmail.com",
          "primary":false
        },
         {
          "email_address":"jpsmith@gmail.com",
          "primary":false
        },
         {
          "email_address":"johnsmith111@gmail.com",
          "primary":false
        }
      ]
}
```

The mapping looks like this:

```json
{
   "mappings":{
      "properties":{
         "given_name":{
            "type":"keyword",
            "fields":{
               "search":{
                  "type":"search_as_you_type"
               }
            }
         },
         "family_name":{
            "type":"keyword",
            "fields":{
               "search":{
                  "type":"search_as_you_type"
               }
            }
         },
         "email_addresses":{
            "type":"nested",
            "properties":{
               "email_address":{
                  "type":"keyword",
                  "fields":{
                     "search":{
                        "type":"search_as_you_type"
                     }
                  }
               },
               "primary":{
                  "type":"boolean"
               }
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

I am running a prefix search on `given_name`, `family_name` and `email_addresses`. This will allow the user to start typing and relevant results from those fields should start returning:

```json
{
   "query":{
      "bool":{
         "should":[
            {
               "nested":{
                  "path":"email_addresses",
                  "query":{
                     "prefix":{
                        "email_addresses.email_address.search": {
                          "value":"j"
                        }
                     }
                  }
               }
            },
            {
               "multi_match":{
                  "query":"j",
                  "fields":[
                     "given_name.search",
                     "family_name.search"
                  ],
                  "type": "bool_prefix"
               }
            }
         ]
      }
   }
}
```

I'd like to sort the results from the above by the best matching `email_address` in `email_addresses` if there is one or more matching `email_address` under `email_addresses`, otherwise to use the `email_address` under `email_addresses` where `primary` is `true`.

I have looked into a script for sorting, but I didn't find anyway to access the matched nested child in a script in the documentation.

Is there anyway to achieve this?

Comment: Do you want to sort nested fields or parent document based on master nested field document?

Comment: I want to sort the parent documents, based on the value in the child document using the matched child document, or a default document if no child documents match.

Comment: ````"sort": [
    {
      "email_addresses.email_address": {
        "order": "asc",
        "missing": "_last", 
        "nested_path": "email_addresses",
        "nested_filter": {
            "prefix": {
              "email_addresses.email_address.search": {
                "value": "j"
              }
            }
        }
      }
    }
  ]````

Comment: problem in your issue is missing  field. missing only supports first, last and a custom numeric value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To do this, we can use a `bool` query in the nested sort.

Given we have the following 4 documents:

```json
{
    "given_name":"John",
    "family_name":"Smith1",
    "email_addresses": [
        {
          "email_address":"someguy50@example.com",
          "primary":true
        },
        {
          "email_address":"someguy51@example.com",
          "primary":false
        },
         {
          "email_address":"someguy52@gmail.com",
          "primary":false
        },
         {
          "email_address":"someguy53gmail.com",
          "primary":false
        }
      ]
}


{
    "given_name":"John",
    "family_name":"Smith2",
    "email_addresses": [
        {
          "email_address":"someguy54@example.com",
          "primary":true
        },
        {
          "email_address":"johnsmith@example.com",
          "primary":false
        },
         {
          "email_address":"someguy55@gmail.com",
          "primary":false
        },
         {
          "email_address":"someguy56gmail.com",
          "primary":false
        }
      ]
}

{
    "given_name":"John",
    "family_name":"Smith3",
    "email_addresses": [
        {
          "email_address":"someguy49@example.com",
          "primary":true
        },
        {
          "email_address":"someguy47@example.com",
          "primary":false
        },
         {
          "email_address":"someguy48@gmail.com",
          "primary":false
        },
         {
          "email_address":"someguy46gmail.com",
          "primary":false
        }
      ]
}

{
    "given_name":"John",
    "family_name":"Smith4",
    "email_addresses": [
        {
          "email_address":"someguy45@example.com",
          "primary":true
        },
        {
          "email_address":"someguy44@example.com",
          "primary":false
        },
         {
          "email_address":"someguy43@gmail.com",
          "primary":false
        },
         {
          "email_address":"someguy42gmail.com",
          "primary":false
        }
      ]
}
```

We can write our query like so:

```json
{
   "query":{
      "bool":{
         "should":[
            {
               "nested":{
                  "path":"email_addresses",
                  "query":{
                     "prefix":{
                        "email_addresses.email_address.search":{
                           "value":"john"
                        }
                     }
                  }
               }
            },
            {
               "multi_match":{
                  "query":"john",
                  "fields":[
                     "given_name.search",
                     "family_name.search"
                  ],
                  "type":"bool_prefix"
               }
            }
         ]
      }
   },
   "sort":[
      {
         "email_addresses.email_address":{
           "order" : "asc",
            "nested":{
               "path":"email_addresses",
               "filter":{
                  "bool":{
                     "should":[
                        {
                           "prefix":{
                              "email_addresses.email_address.search":{
                                 "value":"john"
                              }
                           }
                        },
                        {
                           "term":{
                              "email_addresses.primary": true
                           }
                        }
                     ]
                  }
               }
            }
         }
      }
   ]
}
```

First we do a prefix search on the `email_addresses.email_address`, `given_name` and `family_name`.

Then we sort on the nested `email_addresses` field as follows:

- Sort by the `email_addresses.email_address` that matches our query.
- Sort by `email_address.primary = true`.

The way this works is that in the bool query, Elasticsearch will first find documents that matches the first query under `should` and sort those documents. For the remaining documents that do not match, it will proceed to the next query, which in our case is `email_address.primary = true`. If there are more documents that do not match either of these queries, they will be ordered using an order predetermined by Elasticsearch.